# How to automatically update FileZilla?

Tags: macos, automation, filezilla

Everytime I open FTP client software FileZilla, there is a new version that I need to manually download and install.   How can I  automate the process so it is not as obtrusive,prompting me to update every time I start the software?

I'm on Mac, but how can this process be automated in general?

Comment: This happens to me on Windows and it seems they don't have an internal update mechanism. Although I don't get asked _all_ the time, when I update I get taken to the FileZilla SourceForge page to install the complete new version... not a problem because it still keeps my site manager profiles... I just put it down to "one of those things".

Comment: Is the update optional? Simply say no and get back to FTPing.

Comment: @Wutnaut, do you realize this is not a solution? I ask how to do A automatically. And you basically said don't do A.

Comment: @qazwsx do you realize this is the comment section? When I submit an answer, I'll submit it to the answer area. The problem, as far as I can tell, is that you're burdened by this prompt and subsequent action. IF THE ACTION IS OPTIONAL, SKIPPING THE ACTION IS AN ACTUAL SOLUTION! There's no need to berate me for offering a simple work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use homebrew ([The Hidden Package Manager for OSX](http://brew.sh/))

then just `brew upgrade` in terminal.app and everything installed with homebrew (filezilla) is also upgraded. Silently, Quickly, automatically. Its also possible to schedule that command to happen at custom intervals with *cron*, but I have little success in that field.

EDIT: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/filezilla.rb

Comment: `brew search filezilla` finds no formula.

Comment: It looks pretty simple to write one. ./configure && make && make install for source, or use the dmg tool for bottled.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Brew enough to understand the comment.  How does this added instruction enable me to do update using Brew?

Comment: I do not use apple, so therefore I cannot know entirely how different tools work. HomeBrew is designed to be a source based package management system. The instructions "./configure && make && (sudo) make install" are the basic instructions for "compiling" software from source. Filezilla is free open source software, so it is compatible with homebrew. I had meant for you to write the brew installation script so that you could use it, and afterwards use Brew's upgrade manager to re-run that script and upgrade the software, from source, optimized to your system from the commandline.

Comment: The creators have the comment "under the hood, it is all git and Ruby" so experience you have with that would optimize your experience. because of the nature of git, there would not be a need for a package maintainer, as upgrades are constant; therefore, by writing the formula, you add filezilla to the package database (your own or the world) and get to rest easy.

Comment: Unless I have the whole process completely wrong, once again because I have no mac to test with, it seems like a straightforward process.

Comment: @qazwsx please read my previous comments. INB4 admin saying that this (comment|answer) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There should be *Install new version* on the new version notification dialog.

If you do not get it, FileZilla probably has problems downloading the update automatically.

Are you behind a proxy? You may need to configure it in *Edit > Settings > Connection > Generic proxy*.

[image: FileZilla Check for Updates dialog]

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP is complaining that on a MAC he has to click "Install new version" and then download the app, and drag it to the Apllications folder. It is quite annoying.